# How to delete a block of text in a file Shell Script?

Tags: linux, sh

I have the following scenario I have a block of text and example

```
basketball:
 ball: round
```

being that I don't know exactly what's inside basketball: but I like to delete everything inside it example:

```
men:
  height: 170
  athlete: basketball
women:
  height:180
  athlete: basketball
```

I want to delete only the men block ignoring whatever is above or below this key

Comment: If this is in reality a structured format like YAML, probably use a language which is able to parse the structure.

Comment: Are you saying all those lines are in the same file? Or is that two sets of example data? If one file, please combine the lines to show the actual file content to eliminate the ambiguity. If it is two files and you want to remove the `men:` block, then you can simply use `awk 'NF==1 && $1=="men:" {n=1; next}; NF==1 {n=0} n==0'` file`

Answer (score 0):

The AWK script `filter.awk` below removes all *men* sections which contains basketball. Is that what you mean? Run with `awk -f filter.awk input.txt`.

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]/ {
    if (sectionWanted) {
        printf "%s", section
    }
    sectionWanted = 1
    section = ""
    sectionName = $1
}

/basketball/ && sectionName == "men:" {
    sectionWanted = 0
}

{
    section = section $0 "\n"
}

END {
    if (sectionWanted) {
        printf "%s", section
    }
}
```

Comment: [how I can do that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638570/how-te-remove-the-last-block-on-yaml-with-sh-or-sed)